# Designing the database access layer

Tags: c#, oop, architecture, database-connection

I consider myself quite amateur when it comes to designing a system's architecture, and I currently find myself in the process of doing just that.

Particularly, I am trying to come up with an efficient and maintainable way to re-implement all classes that have methods/functions that query the database to read data, then send it upstream for another layer to process it, and finally receive the processed data to write it back to the database.

Surely this generic problem has already been solved. I intend to follow a DDD approach, so that the methods accessing the database are part of an "Infrastructure" layer. Is there an optimal way of designing a system (or structure of classes) to accomplish this? Should I have just one gateway to read/write from the database that all classes should refer to, or should each components have its own way of communicating with the database? Is there a standard approach to do this?

I am mindful that the question might be a bit broad, but for the experts out there surely you have gone through this and are able to help.

Comment: I think when talking about architectural solutions, no standards here... it all depends which parts of applications are supposed to be changed recently, how separate are the teams working on project and etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are following items to be considered:

- DAO pattern - Create DAO layer leveraging DAO objects (for each domain object) where upper layer (such as service layer) can make use of it.
- Architecture - If you are thinking about micro-services architecture, then UI, Service, DB access (DAO) & DB - all these will be single deployable unit. Hence, design pattern will be aligned to chosen architectural approach.
- API Gateway - An API gateway (aligned with architectural approach). Think about functional use-cases while designing APIs rather than just providing CRUD operations or technology specific APIs.

Answer (score 0):

As an accepted practice, your presentation layer, business logic and data access(some call it back end layer) should be fairly separated. Microst's MVC concept is just a sensible example of dedicated effort to achieve this. AngularJs from Google is another example of MVVM that is to write clean code on client side as opposed to Asp.net MVC server side. So what should be the best practices is clearly established here. As for your question, I would say to design something qualify for highly optimized designing paradigm does not require a certain way but an experience of knowing somany ways and wisdom to choose single or multiple ways or even mixing them to suit your needs. As for your question about gateway to data access, let me put it this way, maintain multiple connections is a very resource consuming job so ideally a single static instance data class in which  a single connection is maintained is an appropriate approach and all the data serving, manipulating methods should be put in there. In web development, we are familiar with webservices exposing objects with operation / message contracts. Separation and encapsulation is the key here. But be sure nothing is perfect, though Asp.net MVC boasts the best methodology of separating all these layers, they have Razor to contradict it. But it's necessary. Hell with being paranoid with tightly coupled back and front end or spaghetti code. It all makes sense when it suits your needs. The key here only experience can teach us the optimize way or ways to do something. That's the returned value of my answer!